# Why are my properties assigning incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

I created an `ObservablePropertyList` which is supposed to execute a callback when a property changes. The implementation is:

```
function ObservablePropertyList(nameCallbackCollection) {
    var propertyList = {};

    for (var index in nameCallbackCollection) {

        var private_value = {};

        propertyList["get_" + index] = function () { return private_value; }
        propertyList["set_" + index] = function (value) {

            // Set the value
            private_value = value;

            // Invoke the callback
            nameCallbackCollection[index](value);
        }
    }

    return propertyList;
}
```

And here's a quick test demonstration:

```
var boundProperties = BoundPropertyList({
    TheTime: function (value) {
        $('#thetime').text(value);
    },
    TheDate: function (value) {
        $('#thedate').text(value);
    }
});

var number = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    boundProperties.set_TheTime(new Date());
    boundProperties.set_TheDate(number++);
}, 500);
```

For some reason though, the properties are not being assigned correctly or something. That is, calling `set_TheTime` for some reason executes the callback for `set_TheDate`, almost as though it were binding everything to only the last item in the list. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is it possible you're just missing the `new` keyword when you're assigning the boundProperties var?

Comment: Nah, that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You may find this enlightening (the whole course is great but this and the next few slides should explain). http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using loops like that you need to wrap it in an enclosure

```
function ObservablePropertyList(nameCallbackCollection) {
    var propertyList = {};

    for (var index in nameCallbackCollection) {
        (function(target){
           var private_value = {};

           propertyList["get_" + index] = function () { return private_value; }
           propertyList["set_" + index] = function (value) {

               // Set the value
               private_value = value;

               // Invoke the callback
               target(value);
           }
        })(nameCallbackCollection[index]);
    }

    return propertyList;
}
```

Comment: Gah, I thought that might be the case. Why is that though?

Comment: Huh, but that sounds right? The `nameCallbackCollection` doesn't change, it's still the same set, just a different index. I guess I don't fully understand...

Comment: edited, was passing the wrong variable. And it happens because the anon function will use whatever was the last visible value of a variable that is in the outerscope.

Comment: for instance here the last visible value of nameCallbackCollection is nameCallbackCollection["TheDate"]

Comment: As weird as this behavior is, it seems to be correct. I need to do more research.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a closure in order for each iteration of the `for` loop to have its own `private_variable` object. Otherwise, each iteration just overwrites the previous (since `private_variable` is hoisted to the top of its scope). I'd set it up like this:

```
var ObservablePropertyList = (function () {
    "use strict";

    var handleAccess = function (propList, key, callback) {
        var privValue = {};

        propList["get_" + key] = function () {
            return privValue;
        };
        propList["set_" + key] = function (value) {
            // Set the value
            privValue = value;

            // Invoke the callback
            callback(value);
        };
    };

    return function (coll) {
        var propertyList = {}, index;

        for (index in coll) {
            handleAccess(propertyList, index, coll[index]); 
        }

        return propertyList;
    };
}());

var boundProperties = ObservablePropertyList({
    TheTime: function (value) {
        $('#thetime').text(value);
    },
    TheDate: function (value) {
        $('#thedate').text(value);
    }
}), number = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    boundProperties.set_TheTime(new Date());
    boundProperties.set_TheDate(number++);
}, 500);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PXHDT/

Comment: Yes, this is what I suspected was occurring.